# How to create a database connection from C# to a remote couchbase databse

Tags: c#, couchbase

I am kind of new to couchbase database and trying to write a code  to connect to a remote couchbase server for my first time. I have written a console application in C# where i have a app.config file and the program.cs file.

My app.config file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="couchbaseClients">
      <section name="couchbase"
               type="Couchbase.Configuration.Client.Providers.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase.NetClient"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <couchbaseClients>
    <couchbase useSsl="false" operationLifeSpan="1000">
      <servers>
        <add uri="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8091/pools"></add>
        <add uri="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8091/pools"></add>
      </servers>
      <buckets>
        <add name="default" useSsl="false" Username="xxxxxx" password="xxxxx" operationLifespan="2000">
          <connectionPool name="custom" maxSize="10" minSize="5" sendTimeout="12000"></connectionPool>
        </add>
      </buckets>
    </couchbase>
  </couchbaseClients>
</configuration>
```

and my Program.cs file is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Couchbase;
using Enyim.Caching.Memcached;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Configuration;

namespace CouchBase_ConnectionTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var cluster = new Cluster("couchbaseClients/couchbase"))
            {
                using (var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket())
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I try to debug the code, it throws an error at code line

```
using (var cluster = new Cluster("couchbaseClients/couchbase"))
```

error message is as follows

> The type initializer for 'Couchbase.Cluster' threw an exception.

Inner exception is as follows

> Failed obtaining configuration for Common.Logging from configuration section 'common/logging

Please help me on this. Thanks in advnce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce the error that you're seeing in this specific setup. However, I do have an answer to your question: "How to create a database connection from C# to a remote couchbase database".

The [CData ADO.NET Provider](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/couchbase/ado) is a driver that allows you access your Couchbase data as if it were a relational database. This is done by wrapping the N1QL REST API into a standards-based driver that incorporates familiar .NET database functionality.

Querying from a bucket is as simple as the following code:

```
string connectionString = "User='myusername';Password='mypassword';Server='http://couchbase40'";
using (CouchbaseConnection connection = new CouchbaseConnection(connectionString)) {
  CouchbaseCommand cmd = new CouchbaseCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer", connection);
  CouchbaseDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  while (rdr.Read()) {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\t{0} --> \t\t{1}", rdr["Name"],     rdr["TotalDue"]));
  }
}
```

You can download a free beta build of the 2016 driver [here](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/couchbase/download/ado).

Comment: Using your answer, I was able to connect to the database. The only thing is, when I try to execute the select command, I get an error as "

 [500] Could not execute the specified command: Configuration system failed to initialize"

The line which the error throws is

`CouchbaseCommand cmd = new CouchbaseCommand("SELECT * FROM KVS", connection);
                CouchbaseDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

ExecuteReader is the line that I get the error

Comment: I was able to solve the error. Its from the Configuration file. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to get things working! For anyone who encounters this error in the future, can you let us know what changes you made in the Configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

With the Couchbase .Net driver, pls make sure you have followed the instructions [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/sdks/dotnet-2.2/getting-started.html) to get it set up fine.

Could you try the following and see if you get a different error?

```
        var config = new ClientConfiguration
        {
            Servers = new List<Uri> { 
                new Uri("http://10.0.0.XX:8091/pools")
            },
            UseSsl = false,
            DefaultOperationLifespan = 1000,
            BucketConfigs = new Dictionary<string, BucketConfiguration>
            {
              {"default", new BucketConfiguration
              {
                  BucketName = "default",
                  UseSsl = false,
                  Password = "",
                  DefaultOperationLifespan = 2000,
                  PoolConfiguration = new PoolConfiguration
                  {
                    MaxSize = 10,
                    MinSize = 5,
                    SendTimeout = 12000
                  }
              }
             }
            }
        };

      Cluster cbCluster = new Cluster(config);
      Document<object> cbDoc = new Document<dynamic> { 
                        Id = _key,
                        Content = new
                        {
                            id = "a"
                        }
                    };

      //UPSERT
      var upsert = cbBucket.Upsert(cbDoc);
      ....
```